# Memory and performance in C++ Game

Tags: c++, memory, directx

I'm still new to C++ but I catch on quick and also have experience in C#. Something I want to know is, what are some performance safe actions I can take to ensure that my game runs efficiently. Also, in which scenario am I likely to run out of memory on. 2k to 3k bullet objects on the stack, or heap? I think the stack is generally faster, but I heard that too much causes a stack overflow. That being said, how much is too much exactly?

Sorry for the plethora of questions, I just want to make sure I don't design a game engine in which it relies on good PCs in order to run well.

Comment: Top tip - use a profiler.  On every platform you want to target.

Comment: On `windows` you can set stack size on during build stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, program your game **safely** and only worry about optimizations like memory layout after **profiling & debugging**.

That being said, I have to dispel the myth that the stack is faster than the heap. What matters is **cache performance**.

The stack generally is faster for small quick accesses, **because the stack usually already is in the cache**. But when you are iterating over thousands of bullet objects on the heap, as long as you store them **contiguously** (e.g. `std::vector`, not `std::list`), everything should be loaded into the cache, and there should be no performance difference.

Comment: I see, thank you for going into detail about the stack. I am already using vectors, so I believe I am on the right path for now. I'll try to not let performance optimizations bother me so much.